# how to sample a file one by one without replacement in R

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

I am working on Monte Carlo Sampling for which I need sampling to be done one by one from a list of files in a folder. I don't want to add any duplicate file. So each file's name is used as the column name. So I want to avoid having two columns with the same name. How can I do so? I have to 100 subsamples so I cant sample each one separately. 
 My code is as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(readr)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(mapdata)
library(sf)
library(data.table)

v<-c(1:500)
loop_N<-dataframe(v)    # dataframe 1 with which all the sampled dataframes will be joined
names(loop_N)<-c("Roads_ID")
loop_N$num_obs<-0
dir<-"Path"
fi <- list.files(dir, pattern="\\.csv$") #list of dataframes as shapefiles 
y1<-500
while(y1>=0){
  sample1 <- sample(fi, 1,replace = FALSE, prob=NULL) # i want each time sampling  with out replacement
  my_spdf<-read_csv(sample1)
  na<-sample1
  d<-substr(na, 1, 18)
  w<- str_replace_all(d,"_","-") # This is for the name of the column which shows me that if same file is sampled it will have the same column names
  addr<-data.frame(r$Row_Rd_No,r$value)    #sampled data frame
  names(addr)<-c("Road_ID",w)
  #dataframe added to loop_N by using Road_ID
  loop_N[, num_obs := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD,function(x) !is.na(x)))]
  loop_N<- subset(loop_N, num_obs != 7)
  y1=nrow(loop_N)
  y1<-as.numeric(y1)
  }
```

[Column names repeated or the same file is sampled: My Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRgKO.png)

[Expected Output To be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNtH7.png)

Comment: See the sample function: `sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!  I did try it but does not seem to work.

Comment: Your code sample above is overly complicated in order to demonstrate your question.  Without any comments, it is difficult to follow the logic.  I suggest you edit the question and only show the relevant parts.  Some sample input and the expected output will more likely lead to receiving a response.

Comment: OK I will reduce the code.